# How to drag and drop SVG file to Fabricjs canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm trying to drag and drop svg img that are outside the canvas to the canvas himself, it does work with simple images (png, jpg, gif) but not with svg files and since I'm new to fabricJS I was wondering how I could configure it so it also works with SVG.
I do not want to create an fabric.Image object from SVGs, i would like to drop them as fabric.PathGroup so that they mantain the vector information and edit capabilities.

You can discover the project on this link :

http://jsfiddle.net/w8kkc/309/

**HTML**

```
<div id="images">
    <img draggable="true" src="http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    <object draggable="true" type="image/svg+xml" data="http://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg" width="100" height="100"></object>
</div>

<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
</div>
```

---

**Javascript (FabricJS)**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

function handleDragStart(e) {
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
    });
    this.classList.add('img_dragging');
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
    // NOTE: comment above refers to the article (see top) -natchiketa

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    // this / e.target is the current hover target.
    this.classList.add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
    }

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
    }

    var img = document.querySelector('#images img.img_dragging');

    // console.log('event: ', e);

    var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
        width: img.width,
        height: img.height,
        // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative
        // to the canvas container.
        left: e.layerX,
        top: e.layerY
    });
    canvas.add(newImage);

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
    // this/e.target is the source node.
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
    });
}

if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {
    // Browser supports HTML5 DnD.

    // Bind the event listeners for the image elements
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('#images img');
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
        img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });
    // Bind the event listeners for the canvas
    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
} else {
    // Replace with a fallback to a library solution.
    alert("This browser doesn't support the HTML5 Drag and Drop API.");
}
```

Any suggestion on how I can accept SVG to be drag and dropped into the canvas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/w8kkc/336/  updated fiddle

#### JAVASCRIPT

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var currentlyDragging;

function handleDragStart(e) {
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
    });
    this.classList.add('img_dragging');
    currentlyDragging = e.target;
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
    // NOTE: comment above refers to the article (see top) -natchiketa

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    // this / e.target is the current hover target.
    this.classList.add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
    }
    
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
    }

 
        
    // console.log('event: ', e);
    var ext = currentlyDragging.src.substr(-3);
    if (ext === 'svg') {
      fabric.loadSVGFromURL(currentlyDragging.src, function(objects, options) {
        var svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        svg.left = e.layerX;
        svg.top = e.layerY;
        canvas.add(svg); 
      });
    } else {
       var newImage = new fabric.Image(currentlyDragging, {
          width: currentlyDragging.width,
          height: currentlyDragging.height,
          // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative
          // to the canvas container.
          left: e.layerX,
          top: e.layerY
      });
      canvas.add(newImage);
    }
    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
    // this/e.target is the source node.
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
    });
}

if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {
    // Browser supports HTML5 DnD.

    // Bind the event listeners for the image elements
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('#images img');
    var objects = document.querySelectorAll('#images object');
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
        img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });
    [].forEach.call(objects, function (obj) {
        obj.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
        obj.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });
    // Bind the event listeners for the canvas
    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
} else {
    // Replace with a fallback to a library solution.
    alert("This browser doesn't support the HTML5 Drag and Drop API.");
}
```

Comment: This works great if you want to load the SVG as an image as if it were a jpg, but you cannot manipulate the SVG or even change the color. To do that I suspect you'll have to get the string from the src and load SVG from string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sunny001/43zvqq2g/2/

I use an `img` tag for the svg:

```
   <img draggable="true" src="http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg" width="100" height="100">
   <img draggable="true" src="http://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg" width="100" height="100"/>
```

All your "drag" code expects an `img` tag, not an `object`(as you had it). I tried adjusting the code to also work with the `object` tag but it didn't work – don't know why, or if it even should.

Comment: I thought about this solution but It doesn't work great since I cannot change the color or the svg live, the file should stay as SVG not IMG.

Comment: @Lindow – ah well. Can't help then (FWIW, you can do some coloring through the [Fabricjs filter API](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters) but that's probably not as discreet as you would like). Oh, as I mentioned, all your "drag" code expects `image` tags so that needs attention.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering on how I could change the "image" expectation ^^

Comment: @Lindow – my hack on your code was to declare a global array and then call `querySelectorAll` for "image", then for "object, dumping the result into that global array, and only then adding the event listeners, etc. I don't know if it is possible to get both types in one call. Anyway – good luck with it.

Comment: ok so reading this comments, your question is at least bad written.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi : huh? I didn't ask a question.

Comment: i was referring to the question maker, not you, sorry.